# error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer

Tags: c#, connection

I just have...

```
public TEntity GetSingle(ISpecification<TEntity> Specification)
    {
        //return this._Context.CreateDbSet<TEntity>()
        //    .SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(Specification.SatisfiedBy());
        if (Specification == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Specification");
        }
        IEnumerable<TEntity> source = this._Context.CreateDbSet<TEntity>().Where(Specification.SatisfiedBy()).AsEnumerable<TEntity>();
        if (source.Count<TEntity>() > 0)
        {
            return source.First<TEntity>();
        }
        return default(TEntity);
    }
```

... which gives me an error when trying to execute this._Context.CreateDbSet()

The error is marked green and the message is something like:

```
Exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MappingException' at mscorlib.dll but it was not caught by user code.
Additional Information: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
Models.Company.CompanyModel.msl(3,4) : error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and AssociationSet in the EntityContainer iOfferEntities.
```

I have the following connection strings at Web.config and App.config like...

```
<add name="iOfferEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Company.CompanyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Company.CompanyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Company.CompanyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=192.168.1.31;initial catalog=mto3;persist security info=True;user id=myuserid;password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have a connection to another database in the same server which I can work with no problems.

Any idea?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I created a new model and got rid of the problematic one. Problem solved so far. Thanks anyway to all.

Comment: This problem occurred for me when I deleted the model and recreated it.  When I recreated the model, it added a 1 to the end of the model name.  So instead of ModelEntities, it was named ModelEntites1.  I was trying to change the name back to just ModelEntities when this error occurred.  In the end, deleting the model, deleting the web.config connection string entry, and recreating the DB First Entity in my database is what I wound up doing.